# If/Else Logic order - Javascript Example - Please explain the difference between these 2 blocks of code

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have spent hours trying to understand this - I know it has something to do with if...else statement logic order, but each time I have tried to follow I got lost. Someone please explain this to me and if possible give a pointer of how to handle if...else logic order(a hack/ quick method to remember e.g: "always start with the larger sample space ...")

Here it is:

> The Task is as follows: We have an array of objects representing
>   different people in our contacts lists.
>
> A lookUpProfile function that takes firstName and a property (prop) as
>   arguments has been pre-written for you.
>
> The function should check if firstName is an actual contact's
>   firstName and the given property (prop) is a property of that contact.
>
> If both are true, then return the "value" of that property.
>
> If firstName does not correspond to any contacts then return "No such
>   contact"
>
> If prop does not correspond to any valid properties then return "No
>   such property"

CODE

This code is wrong

```js
    var contacts = [
        {
            "firstName": "Akira",
            "lastName": "Laine",
            "number": "0543236543",
            "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Harry",
            "lastName": "Potter",
            "number": "0994372684",
            "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Sherlock",
            "lastName": "Holmes",
            "number": "0487345643",
            "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Kristian",
            "lastName": "Vos",
            "number": "unknown",
            "likes": ["Javascript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
        }
    ];
    
    function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop){
      
      for(var i=0;i < contacts.length;i++){
        
        if (contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop))
          {
            if(contacts[i].firstName === firstName){
              return contacts[i][prop];
            }
            else {
              return "No such contact";
            }
    
          }
    // Only change code above this line
    }
      return "No such property";
    }
    // Change these values to test your function
    console.log(lookUpProfile("Harry", "likes"));
```

THIS code is correct:

```js
    var contacts = [
        {
            "firstName": "Akira",
            "lastName": "Laine",
            "number": "0543236543",
            "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Harry",
            "lastName": "Potter",
            "number": "0994372684",
            "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Sherlock",
            "lastName": "Holmes",
            "number": "0487345643",
            "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Kristian",
            "lastName": "Vos",
            "number": "unknown",
            "likes": ["Javascript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
        }
    ];
    
    function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop){
      
      for(var i=0;i < contacts.length;i++){
        
        if (contacts[i].firstName === firstName)
          {
            if(contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)){
              return contacts[i][prop];
            }
            else {
              return "No such property";
            }
    
          }
    // Only change code above this line
    }
      return "No such contact";
    }
    // Change these values to test your function
    console.log(lookUpProfile("Harry", "likes"));
```

I will really appreciate if someone can help me explain the difference. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The difference in these codes is the use of if condition. In the failing code, if the username does not match the parameter-passed name, you are returning from the function. So, when the first item will not match, it will return.

```
if (contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop))
  { 
    //INCORRECT USE OF NAME CHECK IF CONDITION
    if(contacts[i].firstName === firstName){
      return contacts[i][prop];
    }
    else {
      return "No such contact";
    }

  }
```

In the second one, you are going to return only when the first name matches.

```
//CORRECT USE OF IF CONDITION FOR NAME CHECK
if (contacts[i].firstName === firstName)
      {
        if(contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)){
          return contacts[i][prop];
        }
        else {
          return "No such property";
        }

      }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    if (contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop))
      {
        if(contacts[i].firstName === firstName){
          return contacts[i][prop];
        }
        else {
          return "No such contact";
        }
```

So when it encounters a contact with `likes`, but `firstName` not equal to "Harry", it will return "no such contact" immediately.

Answer (score 0):

The `hasOwnProperty()` method returns true or false if an object contains the specified property. In the correct version you are looking for a property(likes) within Harry which returns true. In the invalid one you are looking for a property of an object that is not specified yet so it will always be false.